# jquery autocomplete with typewatch

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am a jQuery newbie and trying to implement the autocomplete functionality along with jQuery typewatch. That is, to get the data from web service after a certain time period say 750 ms rather than after minLength.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.searchinput').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Services/SampleWebService.asmx/GetProduct",
                    data: '{"searchString":"' + request.term + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
        });
        $('.searchinput').typewatch({
            callback: $.autocomplete,
            wait: 750,
            highlight: false
        });
    });
```

My autocomplete thing works absolutely fine but somehow I am not able to include the typewatch thing to it. I am sure there is a serious coding failure which I am not aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery autocomplete have this option as parameter called delay:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay

So what you have to do is to change that parameter, and remove the typewatch as:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.searchinput').autocomplete({
            delay:750,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Services/SampleWebService.asmx/GetProduct",
                    data: '{"searchString":"' + request.term + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter called "delay" is the time you have to wait affter keydown to call external service. That is only for don't overload service with no "sensitive" search data.

What I understood from user question, is that he wants to call the autocomplete "update" function every 750ms.

You could do that changing the typewatch "segment" with this:

```
$('.searchinput').typewatch({
    callback: function(){
        $(".searchinput").data("autocomplete").search();
    },
    wait: 750,
    highlight: false
});
```

That will trigger the search for the service and display popup response every 750ms

Comment: I do not wont to place you -1, but make some tests first. The delay do that. And if you place the typewatch as it is, you need also to type here how you declare the autocomplete.